# Heads or Tails Game - Loop Issues

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Coin {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean validFinalInput = false;
        boolean validBetInput = false;
        boolean validGuessInput = false; //Determines if the guess is a valid input
        boolean validBet = false; //Determines if the bet is valid
        boolean goAgain = true;
        double num; //Unparsed Side Determiner
        double balance = 100; 
        String Bet = null; //Bet Input
        double bet = 0; //Parsed Bet
        String Guess = null; //H or T
        String Side = null; //Determines Side
        String GoAgain = null; //Y/N Retry input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (goAgain == true){ //While true, the player will keep playing.
            num = Math.round(Math.random()); //Declares Number
            if (num == 1){
                Side = "H";
            } else if (num == 0){
                Side = "T";
            } 
            while (validGuessInput == false){ //Determines if the input is valid
                System.out.println("Guess: (H/T)");
                Guess = in.next();
            if (Guess.equals("H") || Guess.equals("T")){
                validGuessInput = true;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Guess!");
                validGuessInput = false;
            }
        }
        while (validBet == false){
            while (validBetInput == false){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Bet? (Your balance is $" + balance);
                    Bet = in.next();
                    bet = Double.parseDouble(Bet);
                    if (bet > 0){
                        validBetInput = true;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Bet!");
                }
            }
            if (bet <= balance && bet >= 0){
                validBet = true;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Bet!");
                validBet = false;
            }
        }
        if (Guess.equals(Side)){
            balance = balance + (bet * 2);
            System.out.println("Correct! The side was: " + Side);
            System.out.println("Your balance is now: $" + balance);
        } else {
            balance = balance - bet;
            System.out.println("Incorrect! The side was: " + Side);
            System.out.println("Your balance is now: $" + balance);
        }
        if (balance == 0){
            System.out.println("You ran out of money. Ending Game.");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Go again? (Y/N)");
        GoAgain = in.next();
        while (validFinalInput == false);
            System.out.println("Go again? (Y/N)");
            GoAgain = in.next();
            validGuessInput = false;
            validBet = false;
            validBetInput = false;
        if (GoAgain.equals("Y")){
            goAgain = true;
            validFinalInput = true;
        } else if (GoAgain.equals("N")){
            goAgain = false;
            validFinalInput = true;
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing! You ended with: $" + balance);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

So I wrote this code for a "Heads or Tails" style game. It originally worked, but then I decided to add a few features, and it busted. Basically, it gets to the end, but is stuck on the last input (Y/N).

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for the lack of commenting.

I also am aware my variables don't quite follow conventions, so sorry for that too.

Thanks.

Comment: You've pasted way too much code.  Parse it down to only the code that is relevant to your actual issue.  Furthermore, there's a reason naming conventions exist.  A boolean named `goAgain` and a String named `GoAgain` makes your code very confusing.

Comment: *I also am aware my variables don't quite follow conventions, so sorry for that too.*: then why don't you fix it before asking the question? Better now than later. It would make your code more readable to all the readers. Have you tried executing the code with a debugger? This is something that you should learn.

Comment: A tip for future code, when code gets this long it is better to split it up in methods. Easier to read, easier to debug and looks prettier if you are shallow like me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove the semicolon here;

   `while (validFinalInput == false)`**;**
2. Indent your code properly.
3. Check your logic here; You are setting validFinalInput = true for both the conditions (true and false).

   if (GoAgain.equals("Y")){
              .........
               validFinalInput = true; }

   else if (GoAgain.equals("N")){
               .......
               validFinalInput = true; }

Comment: A good IDE would catch this. I don't get why people don't use IDE's.

Comment: IDE doesn't necessarily compile.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I didn't catch that. I'm using Eclipse BTW. validFinalInput checks if the input is only Y or N.

Comment: @ModifyYou Please check on some more recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

The value of goAgain never changes in the loop that starts with `while (goAgain == true){` because it ends with the `}` just before `while (validBet == false){`. That closing bracket is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

You have this while statement

```
    while (validFinalInput == false);
```

This is an infinite loop! it will never get past this part of the code because of the semicolon. If you rewrite it like this it should work:

```
     while (validFinalInput == false)
     {
        System.out.println("Go again? (Y/N)");
        GoAgain = in.next();
        validGuessInput = false;
        validBet = false;
        validBetInput = false;
        if (GoAgain.equals("Y"))
        {
        goAgain = true;
        validFinalInput = true;
        } 
        else if (GoAgain.equals("N"))
        {
            goAgain = false;
            validFinalInput = true;
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing! You ended with: $" + balance);
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }
```